# Azure websites (Standard) SSL certificate

Tags: .net, azure, ssl-certificate

I've recently scaled my Azure website to a Standard instance. Azure's pricing tier for Standard says it comes with "5 SNI SSL and 1 IP SSL included at no cost". I'd like to set up SSL binding to my custom domain using one of these supposed "certificates". However, I cannot find anything on the Azure portal pointing me to one of these certificates. The only option is to upload a certificate. Am I wrong in thinking that Azure includes or provides these certificates in Standard mode? Or does "5 SNI SSL and 1 IP SSL included at no cost" mean "SSL slots", but you still have to purchase the certficates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a custom domain you will still have to purchase your own SSL certificate, https is supported on non custom domains for no cost ("Websites provides SSL connections for all URLs under the 'azurewebsites.net' domain at no additional charge. Securely access your website at https://.azurewebsites.net.")

[This](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/) link will show you how to add your custom SSL once you've bought it for your domain.

Comment: Thanks a ton, makes perfect sense! I went ahead and purchased my own SSL certificate, uploaded to Azure, and everything is working great now.